# Platformio No such file or directory when using library form registry

Tags: esp32, platformio

I have problems using libraries in platformio from its registry [fmt](https://registry.platformio.org/libraries/fmtlib/fmt)

My `platformio.ini` file looks like this:

```
[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32dev
framework = espidf
monitor_speed = 115200
monitor_filters = direct time
lib_deps = fmtlib/fmt@^8.1.1
```

And I include it as `#include <fmt/format.h>`

But when building I get the following error

```
In file included from components\tes22\include/tes22/tes22.hpp:4,
                 from components\tes22\src\tes22.cpp:1:
components\tes22\include/tes22/logger.hpp:6:10: fatal error: fmt/format.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <fmt/format.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Edit:

I am using `fmt` inside a component and not the `app_main`